# TypeError statusText: "Internal Server Error" for a simple post "LIKE" feature in Django using Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I have a simple post like toggle button where a user can `like` a post. It is working fine without adding jQuery and Ajax methods. However I need to add Ajax to remove page refresh. Below is my code adding Ajax and jQuery. What am I doing wrong?

I have added the error to the bottom, It says

> got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

How do I fix that?

my models are

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')        
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    message = models.TextField()       
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

    def get_api_like_url(self):
       return reverse('posts:like_api', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                         'slug': self.slug})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('posts:single', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                           'slug': self.slug})

    def get_like_url(self):
       return reverse('posts:like', kwargs={'username': self.user.username,
                                         'slug': self.slug})
```

My views are

```
class PostLikeAPIToggle(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, slug=None, format=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
                liked = False
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
                liked = True
            data = {
                "post": obj,
                "liked": liked,
                "total_likes": obj.likes.all()
            }
            return Response(data)
```

In my template I have the below code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".like-btn").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var this_ = $(this);
            var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href");
            $.ajax({
                url : likeUrl,
                method: "GET",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    // $("#like-section").html(response)
                }, error: function (error) {
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>

<div class="text-center">
{% if user in post.likes.all %}
    <a class="like-btn" data-href="{{post.get_api_like_url}}" href="{{post.get_like_url}}">
        <img src="{% static 'images/HEART.RED.png' %}" height="25px">
    </a><br/>
{% else %}
    <!--<a href=""><img src="{% static 'images/HEART.png' %}" height="25px"></a><br/>-->
    <a class="like-btn" data-href="{{post.get_api_like_url}}" href="{{post.get_like_url}}">
        <img src="{% static 'images/HEART.png' %}" height="25px">
    </a><br/>
{% endif %}
```

Below is my URL for calling the like button

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/like_api/$', views.PostLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='like_api'),
```

Below is the error that I am getting

> responseText: "TypeError at /posts/charlize/singes-boat-new-york/like_api\nget() **got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'\n\nRequest** Method: GET\nRequest URL:

Comment: Totally unrelated but 1/ this `if user in obj.likes.all()` is grossly inefficient - you want `if obj.likes.filter(user=user).exists()` instead (and do not forget to fix it in your templates too), and 2/ a GET request **MUST** be idempotent (it must NOT change the server state) - you want a POST request here, definilty.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thank you so much for that I will definitely update my code accordingly and check the POST options

Comment: About the "POST options" (hint: we're not talking "options" here - it is MANDATORY that a GET request is idempotent), you may want to read this: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL pattern captures `username` and `slug`:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/like_api/$', views.PostLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='like_api')
```

These values are passed to `PostLikeAPIToggle`, but its `get` method doesn't expect to receive `username`.

You don't appear to need `username` since you get the user from `request.user` in your view method, so I recommend changing your URL pattern not to capture the user name:

```
url(r'^[-\w]+/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/like_api/$', views.PostLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='like_api')
```

You could remove that segment entirely, which is even cleaner:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/like_api/$', views.PostLikeAPIToggle.as_view(), name='like_api')
```

The other option would be to update `PostLikeApiToggle.get` to accept `username`, but since you're not using that value it probably isn't the right decision.

Comment: Is there another way to add username to the view. I tried changing the URL and also had to change the  `def get_api_like_url(self):` in the models which is breaking a lot of code in my other pages. I tried changing my views to `def get(self, request, slug=None, username=None, format=None):`  that is giving me `'Post' is not JSON serializable` error

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "add username to the view"? Yes, you'd have to change your call to `reverse()` to no longer provide the username. How does that break code in other pages?

Comment: The "is not JSON serializable" error is a new issue. You're trying to include it as your `"post"` in the server response, but Django doesn't know how to turn your `Post` object into JSON. You can [tell it how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895/354577), or manually populate the fields you need.